# Dirichlet L-function and convergence of $\sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\chi$ be the nontrivial Dirichlet character modulo $4$, and let $L(s,\chi)$ be the Dirichlet L-function

$$L(s,\chi) = 1 - \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} - \cdots = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} = \prod\limits_p (1- \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s})^{-1}$$

which converges absolutely for $\Re s > 1$.  This L-function is in fact analytic on $\Re s > 0$ and satisfies $L(1,\chi) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.  Now for $\sigma > 1$,

$$\log L(\sigma,\chi) = \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}} + G(\sigma)$$

where $G(\sigma) = \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)^n}{np^{n\sigma}}$ converges absolutely for $\sigma > \frac{1}{2}$.

If I have understood all this correctly, then we should have

$$\sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p} = \lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+} \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}} = \log L(1,\chi) + G(1) = \log \frac{\pi}{4} + G(1) < \infty$$

But the series $\sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is conditionally convergent, since $\sum\limits_p \frac{1}{p}$ diverges.  So how can we say that the sum $\sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is an unambiguous finite real number?  Conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to have an arbitrary limit.

Comment: Since $\log L(s,\chi)$ is analytic at $s=1$, if $\sum_{p^k} \chi(p^k)\frac{p^{-k}}{k}$ converges then it is to $\log  L(s,\chi)$. And its convergence is really the same as the PNT : zero-free region for $\prod_{\chi\bmod q} L(s,\chi)$, a bound for $\log L(s,\chi)$ in this region and a contour shift in $\frac{\log L(s,\chi)}{s+1}$'s inverse Mellin transform (the whole thing is a tauberian theorem).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: PNT = prime number theorem, its proof is complicated and involves the steps I mentioned (with $\zeta(s)$ instead of $L(s,\chi)$)

Comment: But what is wrong with my reasoning that $\sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ exists as a limit $\lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+} \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}}$?

Comment: It is obvious that $\lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+} \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}}$ exists but that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{p \le x} \chi(p)/p$ exists is a deep theorem similar to the PNT. It is not hard to show if the 2nd exists then it is the same as the 1st

Comment: Ah, I think I am beginning to see.  So $\lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+}\frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}}$ exists and is equal to $L(1,\chi) + G(1)$, right?  And is it possible to interpret $\lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+} \sum\limits_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{\sigma}}$ as a conditionally convergent series in some arrangement of the terms $\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$?

Comment: Note $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\log(n)$ don't exist but $\lim_{s \to 0} \eta(s),\lim_{s \to 0} \eta'(s)$ both exist, so a priori it could be the same for $\sum_p \chi(p) / p$, and for showing it is not you need a bunch of properties of L-functions

Comment: You said so, rearranging $\sum_p \chi(p)/p$ converges to what you want, so you can interpret it the way you want (it won't be meaningful). Only $ \sum_{p \le x} \chi(p)/p$ can be interpreted as the inverse Mellin transform of $\log L(s,\chi)/(s+1) $

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies on the fact that by saying $$L(1,\chi)=\frac{\pi}{4}<\infty$$ you are already using the formula 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}=-\log(1-x)$$ to define the value $L(1,\chi)$ for $\chi\neq 1$, even if this series only converges conditionally for $\vert x\vert=1$ and $x\neq 1$.

To see this in general, suppose $\chi$ is a non-trivial primitive Dirichlet character mod N, you can define the Gauss sum to be 
$$\tau(\chi)=\sum_{n \mod N}\chi(n)\psi(n)$$ where $\psi(n)=\exp(2\pi i n/N)$. Using this one can show that the equality holds:

$$\sum_{n\mod N}\chi(n)\psi(nm)=\overline{\chi(m)}\tau(\chi).$$

Since $\chi(-1)\overline{\tau(\chi)}=\tau(\overline{\chi})$, together with the fact that $\tau(\chi)\overline{\tau(\chi)}=\vert\tau(\chi)\vert^2=N$, one can rewrite this as
$$\chi(n)=\frac{\chi(-1)\tau(\chi)}{N}\sum_{m\mod N}\overline{\chi(m)}\psi(nm)=\frac{\chi(-1)\tau(\chi)}{N}\sum_{m\mod N}\overline{\chi(m)}\psi(m)^n,$$ now we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\frac{\chi(-1)\tau(\chi)}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m\mod N}\overline{\chi(m)}\frac{\psi(m)^n}{n}$$
$$=\frac{\chi(-1)\tau(\chi)}{N}\sum_{m\mod N}\overline{\chi(m)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi(m)^n}{n}$$ Then use the above identity you can define
$$L(1,\chi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\frac{\chi(-1)\tau(\chi)}{N}\sum_{m\mod N}\overline{\chi(m)}\log(1-\psi(m))$$ Although the series on the left hand side is conditionally convergent, the right hand side gives you a finite number.

So in your question you are actually using $$\sum\frac{\chi(p)}{p}=\log L(1,\chi)+G(1)$$ to define the value of the series on the left hand side.